# What is generic name for devices like this?

Tags: terminology, vocabulary

Well, problem is programming-related, but main problem is a naming, so I guess it's a correct place to ask.

I have various type of devices designed to affect environment conditions. Typical examples would be heater (affects temperature) or sprinkler (affects humidity). It should turn on/off if measured value are above or below specified limit. So I save a `sensor` to measure conditions and `...` to try to affect these conditions.

Can you think of any generic name (`...`) which would describe this kind of device?

Comment: I think you want *regulator*, or possibly *governor*. (Or, did you ever wonder where the "C" in "AC" came from?)

Comment: I think regulator or governor would be the part that uses the data from the sensor and determines if it should switch the `...` on or off. Maybe `worker` or `actor`?

Comment: Regulator and conditioner and very good responses... To be honest, I guess I had some kind of amnesia 15 minutes ago, now I see how trivial is that.

Comment: Maybe _actuator_ fits better. The regulator is the component between them, that decides whether to turn it on or off based on the sensor reading.

Comment: It turns out this is not the place to ask, as is deemed [out of scope / not
on-topic](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).  I'd recommend stack overflow instead & tag it with [naming-conventions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/naming-conventions).

Answer (score 3):

How about "climate control"

This phrase is normally used to describe systems that impact the immediate environment, such as air conditioners, heaters, dehumidifiers, and the like.

For example, in automotive design the phrase "climate control system" is used to describe the parts of the vehicle that are involved in heating the interior of the car, cooling the interior of the car, and related.

Answer (score 1):

How about *responder*, meaning something that responds to a situation?  The most familiar modern use is in the phrase *first responders* meaning the personnel (police, firemen, coast guard) who respond to emergencies like fires, bombs, hurricanes and so forth, but it could be easily applied to this new context.